# FFMPEG remove step of creating overlay video in multistep process

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a multistep process to generate a downloadable copy of a livestream with onscreen elements being burned into the video.

First command generates a transparent animated overlay from a frame list in a text file.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic -f concat -safe 0 -r 30 -vcodec png  -i /tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/36000/bt_files.txt -r 30 -codec:v png /tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/36000/d8d55cd61873959017ed8dce8a0dcb61.mov
```

The text file contains a sequence of frames for an animation that has "opening frames" and then loop frames, essentially:

```
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00001.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00002.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00003.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00004.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00005.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00006.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00007.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00008.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00009.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00010.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00005.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00006.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00007.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00008.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00009.png
/tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/img/00010.png
...
```

repeated until the frame count is reached (in this case 36000 frames).

The resultant MOV file is in the 2gb range as it's basically just a container with the frames images copied into.

The next step intermediate file is generated using multiple overlays.  The MOV above, text that gets displayed after 40 frames and stays static until end, and a second overlay "watermark" style image.

```
ffmpeg  -i /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/51039542.mp4  -vf "movie=/tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/bt_51039542.mov[inner];movie=/tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/bt_51039542_blank.png[overlay];movie=/tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/cover.png[cover];[in][inner] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-15 [out];[out][overlay] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-15:enable='between(n,40,36000)' [fin];[fin][cover] overlay=0:0 [final]" -shortest -b:v 5000k  -f mpegts /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/intermediate.ts
```

I'd like the avoid the step of creating the animated MOV file and combine both steps into a single command mainly to avoid having to store such a large file temporarily.

---

One alternative I've considered but not yet tried is to generate 2 MOV files.  The "entry" and then the "loop" sequence and looping the second file instead of generating an complete set of frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply specify the concat input directly as the 2nd input and use that for overlay. Same for other inputs used in further overlays.

`ffmpeg -i /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/51039542.mp4 -f concat -safe 0 -r 30 -i /tmp/bottomThird/UNKNOWN/36000/bt_files.txt -i /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/bt_51039542_blank.png -i /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/cover.png -filter_complex "[0][1] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-15 [out];[out][2] overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-15:enable='between(n,40,36000)' [fin];[fin][3] overlay=0:0" -shortest -b:v 5000k -f mpegts /tmp/embedGenerator/51039542/intermediate.ts`

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks.